# Gnome mplayer and vlc showing blue, black screen output at every video

Tags: drivers, video, vlc

I recently installed lubuntu 15.10 and Gnome mplayer was already installed in it, but every time play any video it just shows this [image: gnome mplayer] and then i installed vlc media player to solve the issue but didn't work [image: vlc media player]. I checked if all required drivers are installed or not in Prefrences>additional drivers but it does not show any additional driver require, what should I do to make it work? 
PS: my pc is an old pentium four.

Comment: did you install [ubuntu-restricted-extras](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats)???

Comment: @incBrain the link is not working and I don't know what these ububtu restricted extras are and I installed lubuntu.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras` for lubuntu

Comment: i installed them but it doesn't help, what else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type:
**sudo apt-get update**
 **sudo apt-get install mplayer2**

Reboot your pc and try again.

If the problem still exist try this:
**Open VLC**-**Tools**-**Preferences**, Click on **Video** tab and change the **Output** until you see any changes.

**Optional:** *try the **latest** smplayer.*

**sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install smplayer**

Comment: it is asus p5p800 vm motherboard and has intel extreme graphics 2. I think I don't have drivers to play the video.